# export gpx file with python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

i want to export (download) a gpx file from https://routing.openstreetmap.de
when u request directions the url is like this:
https://routing.openstreetmap.de/?z=17&center=51.515199%2C-0.092772&loc=51.514739%2C-0.089800&loc=51.516214%2C-0.096656&hl=en&alt=0&srv=1

[image]

using python i want to export the gpx file after inserting a new loc=lat-lon&loc=lat-lon to the url.
after inspecting the site this the span class to download.

[image]

please guys. at least a hint

**EDITED this part is added after answer**

here is the gpx file for
https://routing.openstreetmap.de/?z=15&center=36.614839%2C3.014159&loc=36.600473%2C2.994676&loc=36.623863%2C3.002186&hl=en&alt=0&srv=2

[image]

and with the json request i get only two points with this code:

```
import requests
import json

lat_start = 36.5924
lon_start = 2.9898

lat_dist = 36.6429
lon_dist = 2.9929

url = 'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/'+ str(lat_start)+','+str(lon_start)+';'+str(lat_dist)+','+str(lon_dist)+'?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true'
#url = 'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/-0.0898,51.514739;-0.096656,51.516214?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true'
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()
print('DATA ___________________________________________________')
print(data)
mrks = []
for elements in data['routes']:
    #print('ROUTES___________________________________________________')
    #print(elements)
    for legs in elements['legs']:
        #print('legs___________________________________________________')
        #print(legs)
        for steps in legs['steps']:
            #print('steps___________________________________________________')
            #print(steps)
            for intersections in steps['intersections']:
                #print('intersections___________________________________________________')
                #print(intersections)
                for location in intersections['location']:  
                    #print(location)
                    mrks.append(location)

#print(mrks)
twin = []
for i in range(0, len(mrks),2):
    twin.append(str(mrks[i])+'___'+str(mrks[i+1]))
print('points ___________________________________________________')   
for points in twin:
    print(points)
```

Comment: first check if you see this `<span>` in browser when you turn off JavaScript. If you can see then you can try to use `requests` with `beautifulsoup` to search it. If it needs JavaScript then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: do you need it as gpx? it seems it get data from server as JSON: https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-bike/route/v1/driving/-0.0898,51.514739;-0.096656,51.516214?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true

Comment: i can c it yes when javascript is disabled . the gpx file has waypoints inside thats what i  actually need to get an output in my app

Comment: I tested it with Slenium. It seems it uses JavaScript to get data from API as JSON and it creates data in memory (`blob` with gpx data), and when you click it then it sends data (`blob`) directly from memory - so there is no URL to get it. And when I use `click()` then it ask for folder and this needs manuall click. The simplest is to get JSON from API.

Comment: the JSON file u pasted up has everything inside i can readout the data from it. but how to request it with python how can i generate it from a url . i mean what module shall i use. srry i m bad at handling js

Comment: yes it works can u please tell me how did u get this link or the translation of this one https://routing.openstreetmap.de/?z=17&center=51.515540%2C-0.090975&loc=51.514759%2C-0.089940&loc=51.516661%2C-0.092429&hl=en&alt=0&srv=0 . the first one was for bikes and this one is for cars. abd thank u SOOOOOO much bro

Comment: done bro u just change  'bike' to 'car'.  i cant thank u enough

Comment: @furas it seems that the gpx file has more points than whats in the jason. for the same start lat and lon the gpx file has more output. downloading gpx from this url
 https://routing.openstreetmap.de/?z=15&center=36.614839%2C3.014159&loc=36.600473%2C2.994676&loc=36.623863%2C3.002186&hl=en&alt=0&srv=0   with python m using this url for json request  rl = 'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/route/v1/driving/36.5924,2.9898;-36.6429,2.9929?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true'   i redited the question to add info

Comment: it seems link to JSON needs values in different order - `long,lat` but gpx needs `lat,long` ?

Comment: it seems there is some documentation [Routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and there is python module [PyrouteLib](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PyrouteLib)

Comment: yes thats it bro. thanku so much and sorry for burning ur brain cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it uses `JavaScript` to get data from API as JSON and it creates data in memory (`blob` with `gpx` data), and when you click it then it sends data (`blob`) directly from memory - so there is no URL to get it. And when I use `click()` then it asks for folder and this needs manual click.

It seems it is simpler to get `JSON` than `gpx`
and `url` to `JSON` data also uses `-0.0898,51.514739;-0.096656,51.516214`

---

**EDIT:** Link to web page uses `lat,lon` but link to JSON needs `lon,lat`

---

```py
import requests

start_lon = -0.0898    # can be also as text
start_lat = 51.514739  # can be also as text

end_lon = -0.096656    # can be also as text
end_lat = 51.516214    # can be also as text

data = f"{start_lon},{start_lat};{end_lon},{end_lat}"

transport = 'bike'  # 'car', 'foot'

url = f'https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-{transport}/route/v1/driving/{data}'

payload = {
    'overview': 'false',     # can't be True/False
    'alternatives': 'true',  # can't be True/False
    'steps': 'true',         # can't be True/False
}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(response.url)
#print(response.text)
print('---')

data = response.json()

for point in data['waypoints']:
    print('name:', point['name'])
    print('distance:', point['distance'])
    print('location:', point['location'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
url: https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-bike/route/v1/driving/-0.0898,51.514739;-0.096656,51.516214?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true
---
name: Princes Street
distance: 4.955845
location: [-0.089734, 51.514722]
---
name: Gresham Street
distance: 8.8597
location: [-0.096605, 51.516287]
---
```

---

**EDIT:**

Some documentation for [Routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and python modules [PyrouteLib](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PyrouteLib), [SimpleOsmRouter](https://github.com/F6F/SimpleOsmRouter)